# POST error 400 "beer name must be defined"

Tags: reactjs

I have an event handler for submitting an entry into an API. The API is a beer list and I am trying to submit my entry back into the API through an ON ADD method. When I submit my entry I get a 400 error but not a BAD REQUEST. The error preview says error: "Beer Name must be defined."

I believe my issue lies in my JSON stringify params but I am unsure what to put in that field. Some advice would be great. Thank you.

```
 onSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    fetch("https://beer.fluentcloud.com/v1/beer", {
      body: JSON.stringify(),
      headers: {
        "Accept" : "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      method: "POST"
    });

    this.props.onAdd(this.nameInput.value, this.likesInput.value);
    this.nameInput.value = '';
    this.likesInput.value = '';
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You post an empty body, please put object with desired fields populated there, e.g.

```
JSON.stringify({
 name: this.nameInput.value,
 likes: this.likesInput.value
});
```

Also please note that `fetch` API returns `Promise`, so I would modify your code to wait for it resolved:

```
event.preventDefault();
fetch("https://beer.fluentcloud.com/v1/beer", {
  body: JSON.stringify({
    name: this.nameInput.value,
    likes: this.likesInput.value
  }),
  headers: {
    "Accept" : "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  method: "POST"
}).then(() => {
  console.log('Submitted!');
  this.props.onAdd(this.nameInput.value, this.likesInput.value);
  this.nameInput.value = '';
  this.likesInput.value = '';
}).catch(e => console.error('Failed', e));
```

Comment: You're right!  I had to assign objects and then the input values. Thank you so much!